# SQL Server - Calculating like values & using SUM to get total?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query to retrieve a Total count of a value or like values..

This is something I know should be fairly simple, but I am having a mind blank today.

For example, my table is something like this:

```
CustName:        Acct #:    FavColor:

Mr Johnson       12345      Red
Barry Johnson    86749      Dark Red
Mike Johnson     90462      Blue
Ms Smith         85693      Light Blue
```

The table has multiple variations of the color "Red" in the "FavColor" column. That could be "Light Red", "Dark Red", "Red" etc etc..

I just need to know the total count of Customers who like any shade of "Red".

No matter how I write this simple query, the counts are still separating each record into a separate row with a count of '1' each.

So if I run the below query:

```
Select 
    CustName, CustAcct, FavColor, 
    count(case when FavColor like '%Red%' then 1 end) AS [Total_Red],
    count(case when FavColor like '%Blue%' then 1 end) AS [Total_Blue]
From 
    CustTable
Group by 
    CustName, CustAcct, FavColor
```

I get the following results:

```
CustName:        Acct #: |  FavColor:   [Total_Red]  [Total_Blue]  
Mr Johnson       12345      Red              1
Barry Johnson    86749      Dark Red         1
Mike Johnson     90462      Blue                           1
Ms Smith         85693      Light Blue                     1
```

I need the results to show the `[Total_Red]` column value as '2' since there are two customers who like red.

Thank you in advance!

Using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the groupings. It is breaking it out by customer. If you want just a total for the color then you can run something like the below query. This will return the total customers who like each color.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FavColor LIKE '%Red%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total_Red',
    SUM(CASE WHEN FavColor LIKE '%Blue%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total_Blue'
FROM
    CustTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is giving an error. In SQL server, I have to group by something since we are using an aggregate

Comment: @B-Boy This runs fine for me. You do not have to use group by to use an aggregate. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I tried again this morning and this worked great for me!@Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte
as
( 
select 
sum(case when FavColor like '%Red%' then 1 end) AS [Total_Red],
sum(case when FavColor like '%Blue%' then 1 end) AS [Total_Blue],
CustName, CustAcct
from 
table t2
group by CustName, CustAcct
)
select 
c.total_red,c.total_blue, t1.CustName, t1.CustAcct, t1.FavColor
from
cte t1
join
table t2
on 
t1.CustName=t2.CustName
t2.CustAcct=t1.CustAcct
```